# Libjingle webrtc failed to init camera on android 7

Tags: android, webrtc, android-7.1-nougat

I'm using libjingle in one of my project for webrtc video/audio stream and video stream just not working on android 7 for no reason(at least there is no crashes), it works fine on android 4,5,6. Had anyone face this issue already?

Comment: can you give a code snippet that where it's crashing or the Crash Report

Comment: Abir Hasan, thx for help, but I solved the issue by moving to fresh version of webrtc. Seems like the issue was in lib itself, too old to handle android 7 file system changes, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got emailed about same issue. Due to a7 changes, you need to update to ~fresh webrtc version. If you cant compile it from source code(nothing wrong with you)- here is the ~fresh libjingle with fix (NOTE, code most be redone a little for video to work). 
[Drive archive with libjingle.cc](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-HHUvH7m0XLSlZiVzJEenppblU)

Just put all files from archive to app/src/main/jniLibs and add to your gradle

```
compile files('src/main/jniLibs/autobanh.jar')
compile files('src/main/jniLibs/base_java.jar')
compile files('src/main/jniLibs/libjingle_peerconnection.jar')
```

Archive containes everything for webrtc to work on a7 with every processor type, so you can play with werbrtc on every device and even emulator. Have fun.

***WARNING! 2018 UPDATE***

For everyone still having issues with webrtc versioning, you dont need to build it anymore from sources, just visit https://bintray.com/google/webrtc/google-webrtc, pick version and implement it into your build.gradle, feels good

exmaple:

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.21217'
}
```

Comment: I didn't find the updated libjingle_peerconnection library. I am getting exception E/libjingle: (physicalsocketserver.cc:898): pipe failed. Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @ShashankGupta sorry for late response, check post below, if the issue for you is still actual, thanks